# Android ошибка c toolbar

Tags: android

Хочу запустить из фрагмента, который относится к Navigation Drawer Activity, SmartphoneActivity, который отноcится в TabLayout

Выкидывает ошибку:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.danilshik.testapplication/com.example.danilshik.testapplication.activities.SmartphoneActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:201)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                      at com.example.danilshik.testapplication.activities.SmartphoneActivity.onCreate(SmartphoneActivity.java:25)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Судя по ошибке, ошибка в этой строчке:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

В чем ошибка?

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.SmartphoneActivity">

    <!-- our toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <!-- View pager to swipe views -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

SmartphoneActivity:

```
public class SmartphoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_smartphone);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Main"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Display"));

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        SmartphonePager adapter = new SmartphonePager(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это из-за того, что у вас в стилях приложения указана тема с уже имеющимся `ActionBar` - в итоге конфликт при попытке его переназначить.

Это решается проставлением темы без `ActionBar`:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Comment: в xml layout или manifest?

Comment: @danilshik, в `styles.xml`

Comment: спасибо, добавил